# Comparing one record to another in another data set in Pig

Tags: bigdata, apache-pig, apache-zeppelin

I am a beginner to Pig and I am working with a large business data file.  The business data file has cities from all over the world and I am looking to work with just the US cities.  I have `LOADED` both data sets successfully and am trying to iterate over the total business data file and remove all cities that are not in the US cities dataset.

```
raw_bus_data = LOAD 'globalbus.json' USING com.twitter.elphantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') as (row: map[]);

us_citystate = LOAD 'us.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (city:chararray, state:chararray);
```

I realize this next line doesn't work, but i'm trying to do something similar:

```
bus_us_data = FILTER raw_bus_data BY state == us_citystate state;
```

Is this something i would need to use `FOREACH` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do an inner join which will effectively filter out any rows that don't contain a US state. Because `us_citystate` has multiple rows for each state (one for each city), you will need to create a new relation `B` that contains only one row per state or else you will duplicate rows from `bus_us_data`. The code to do this and the inner join is:

```
A = FOREACH us_citystate GENERATE state;
B = DISTINCT A;
C = JOIN raw_bus_data BY state, B BY state;
bus_us_data = FOREACH C GENERATE 
    raw_bus_data::var1 AS var1, 
    raw_bus_data::var2 AS var2;
```

Where var1, var2, etc. are the fields you wish to retain from `raw_bus_data`.

Comment: Yes, this appears to work, but is appending state data and records on to the end of my current records, which is not intended.  Is there a way to match multiple fields?  Say city and state?  or something to that effect? @savagedata

Comment: I realized there was a problem with my original answer - because `us_citystate` contains multiple rows for each state, joining it with `bus_us_data` will create duplicate rows. I've fixed my answer above and added the solution to keep only the fields from `raw_bus_data`.

Comment: To answer your second question, you can join on more than one field, e.g. `JOIN raw_bus_data BY (city, state), us_citystate BY (city, state);` If you join on both city and state, you do not have to create the relations A and B above because `us_citystate` has only one row for each city and state. The key is for the dataset you're using to filter to only have one row per combination of fields.